# Can the encoding of the default admin (postgres) be changed?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to upgrade from 9.2 to 9.3, pg_upgrade fails because the 9.2 postgres (admin) db is SQL_ASCII and the new 9.3 postgres (admin) instance is UTF-8.

I can't drop the 'postgres' db as it's the admin instance, so I can't recreate with UTF-8.

Am I going about this correctly?

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you drop the (new) postgres database? There is nothing special about that database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could still drop the database. Under Linux, the following shell commands should do the trick (issue as the `postgres` user, use `su - postgres` in a root shell):

  ```
  postgres$ pg_dump postgres > pg.sql
  postgres$ dropdb postgres
  postgres$ createdb -O postgres -E UTF8 postgres
  postgres$ psql < pg.sql
  ```
- Alternatively you can trick the catalog to think the database is in UTF8. This will work for an empty `postgres` database (which is empty by default)

  ```
  postgres$ psql 
  postgres=# UPDATE pg_database SET encoding = pg_char_to_encoding('UTF8') WHERE datname = 'postgres';
  ```

Comment: Excellent, the alternative (UPDATE) worked perfectly, much thanks!